# Properties of topological vector space.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, topological-vector-spaces

> Let $X$ be a topological vector space. Let $\mathcal B$ be a local base at $0.$ Then the following statements hold $:$
>
> $(1)$ $\mathcal U, \mathcal V \in \mathcal B \implies \exists\ \mathcal W \in \mathcal B$ such that $\mathcal W \subset \mathcal U \cap \mathcal V.$
>
> $(2)$ $x \in \mathcal U \in \mathcal B \implies \exists\ V \in \mathcal B$ such that $x + \mathcal V \in \mathcal U.$
>
> $(3)$ $\mathcal V \in \mathcal B, x \in X \implies \exists\ 0 \neq \lambda \in \Bbb C\ (\text {or}\ \Bbb R)$ such that $\lambda x \in \mathcal V.$
>
> $(4)$ $\mathcal U \in \mathcal B \implies \exists\ \mathcal V \in \mathcal B$ such that $\mathcal V + \mathcal V \subseteq \mathcal U.$
>
> $(5)$ $\mathcal U \in \mathcal B \implies \lambda\ \mathcal U \subseteq \mathcal U,\ \forall\ \lambda$ with $|\lambda| \lt 1.$

$(1)$ $:$ It follows from the fact that $\mathcal U \cap \mathcal V$ is an open neighbourhood of $0.$ Now since $\mathcal B$ is a local base at $0$ it follows that there exists $\mathcal W \in \mathcal B$ such that $\mathcal W \subseteq \mathcal U \cap \mathcal V.$

$(2)$ $:$ Since $X$ is a topological vector space the map $f_x : X \longrightarrow X$ defined by $y \mapsto (y - x)$ is a homeomorphism and hence open. Thus $\mathcal U - x$ is an open neighbourhood of $0.$ So there exists $\mathcal V \in \mathcal B$ such that $\mathcal V \subseteq \mathcal U - x \iff x + \mathcal V \subseteq \mathcal U.$

$(3)$ $:$ Since $X$ is a topological vector space the map $g_x : \Bbb C \longrightarrow X$ defined by $\lambda \mapsto \lambda x$ is continuous. In particular $g_x$ is continuous at $0.$ Hence there exists $\varepsilon \gt 0$ such that for all $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ with $|\lambda| \lt \varepsilon$ we have $\lambda x \in \mathcal V.$ Now take any $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ with $0 \lt |\lambda| \lt \varepsilon$ and then we are through.

$(4)$ $:$ Since $X$ is a topological vector space the binary operation $(x,y) \mapsto (x+y)$ is continuous. Using the continuity of the binary operation at $(0,0)$ we get open neighbourhoods $V_1$ and $V_2$ of $0$ such that $V_1 + V_2 \subseteq \mathcal U.$ Find $\mathcal W_1, \mathcal W_2 \in \mathcal B$ such that $\mathcal W_1 \subseteq V_1$ and $\mathcal W_2 \subseteq V_2.$ Then $\mathcal W_1 \cap \mathcal W_2$ is an open neighbourhood of $0.$ So there exists $\mathcal V \in \mathcal B$ such that $\mathcal V \subseteq \mathcal W_1 \cap \mathcal W_2.$ Then by the construction $\mathcal V \subseteq V_1 \cap V_2$ and hence $\mathcal V + \mathcal V \subseteq V_1 + V_2 \subseteq \mathcal U.$

Can anybody please help me proving the last statement i.e. $(5)\ $? I am having hard time in proving this. Also please check my arguments from $(1)$-$(4).$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last statement suggests that every basic open neighbourhood of $0$ contained in $\mathcal B$ is a balanced set. Am I right?

Comment: What I am able to prove is that there exists $\varepsilon \gt 0$ and $\mathcal V \in \mathcal B$ such that $\lambda\ \mathcal V \subseteq \mathcal U,$ for all $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ with $|\lambda| \lt \varepsilon.$ From here how do I conclude $(5)\ $? Can you please help @Eevee Trainer?

Comment: Rudin's Functional Analysis Theorem $1.14$ on-page $12$ says that: In a topological vector space, every neighborhood of $0$ contains a balanced neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @SumantaDas is the soft copy of this book available? I don't have the hard copy of it. Thanks.

Comment: A set $B$ of a topological vector space is said to be **balanced** if $\alpha B\subseteq B$ for each scalar $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|\leq 1$.

Comment: I know that @SumantaDas. Please have a look at my first comment.

Comment: I get it in the ISI E-library. Thanks @SumantaDas.

Comment: Consider $X=\Bbb R$ and $\mathcal U:=(-1,2)$. Is $(5)$ true then?

Comment: @SumantaDas: What I think is that there exists a local base at $0$ where $(5)$ holds. It will not hold for all local base at $0.$ For instance we could have taken all the open neighbourhoods of $0$ for $\Bbb C$ as $\mathcal B$ and then if we rotate each set by an angle $0 \lt \theta \lt \pi$ then the statement $(5)$ wouldn't hold.

Comment: @SumantaDas: No. For instance we could take $\lambda = - \frac {3} {4}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true under your assumption "Let $\mathcal B$ be a local base at $0$." As Sumanta Das comments, take $X = \mathbb R$ and $\mathcal B = \{(−1/n,2/n)\mid n \in \mathbb N\}$. Then no $U \in \mathcal B$ has the property $(−3/4)U \subset U$ although $|−3/4|<1$.

You can show that there exists a local base $\mathcal B'$
at $0$ with properties $(1)−(5)$. Given any $\mathcal B$, for each $U \in \mathcal B$ define $U' = \bigcup_{|λ| \le 1} λU$ and let $\mathcal B'$ be the collection of these $U'$.

Comment: Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $0.$ Then by continuity of the scalar multiplication there exists $\varepsilon \gt 0$ and an open neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ such that for all $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ with $|\lambda| \lt \varepsilon$ we have $\lambda\ V \subseteq U.$ Let $$W = \bigcup\limits_{\substack {\lambda \in \Bbb C} \\ {|\lambda| \lt \varepsilon}} \lambda\ V.$$ Then $W$ is an open neighbourhood of $0,$ balanced and $W \subseteq U.$ That means every open neighbourhood of $0$ contains a balanced open neighbourhood of $0.$

Comment: Let one of the balanced open neighbourhoods of $0$ contained in $U$ be denoted by $B_U.$ Then the collection $\mathcal B = \left \{B_U\ \big |\ 0 \in U, U\ \text {open} \right \}$ is a balanced local base for the topological vector space $X.$ If we started with this local base $\mathcal B$ then we have the access of $(5).$ Am I right sir?

Comment: @Anacardium That is correct.

Comment: Sir can you please have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3980048/512080 I spend almost an hour to prove this but failed. Thanks in advance.